# Sort Array List by past 3 days

Tags: java, date, sorting, arraylist

I am new to java so I need help with the below scenario.

I have an `ArrayList` that stores dates and other information, I want to print the arraylist in which the last 3 days' dates should be on top, the rest is following the same list.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
package learn.java.com;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Person {

private String orderno;
private String itemno;
private Date orderdate;

public String getOrderno() {
    return orderno;
}

public void setOrderno(String orderno) {
    this.orderno = orderno;
}

public String getItemno() {
    return itemno;
}

public void setItemno(String itemno) {
    this.itemno = itemno;
}

public Date getOrderdate() {
    return orderdate;
}

public void setOrderdate(Date orderdate) {
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
}

public Person(String orderno, String itemno, Date orderdate) {
    this.orderno = orderno;
    this.itemno = itemno;
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
}





public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Person("099909","BC101", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("01-01-2010")));
    list.add(new Person("989878","BC102", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("02-01-1990")));
    list.add(new Person("878788","BC103", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("03-01-2000")));
    list.add(new Person("099909","BC104", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("04-01-2010")));
    list.add(new Person("989878","BC105", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("05-01-1990")));
    list.add(new Person("878788","BC106", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("06-01-2000")));
    list.add(new Person("099909","BC107", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("07-01-2010")));
    list.add(new Person("989878","BC108", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("08-01-1990")));
    list.add(new Person("878788","BC109", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("09-01-2000")));

    System.out.println("Before Sort");
    for (Person person : list) {
        System.out.println(person.orderno + " " + person.getItemno()+ " " + person.getOrderdate());
    }



   }
  }
```

**"CURRENT OUTPUT"**

`099909 BC101 Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2010`

`989878 BC102 Tue Jan 02 00:00:00 EST 1990`

`878788 BC103 Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 EST 2000`

`099909 BC104 Mon Jan 04 00:00:00 EST 2010`

`989878 BC105 Fri Jan 05 00:00:00 EST 1990`

`878788 BC106 Thu Jan 06 00:00:00 EST 2000`

`099909 BC107 Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 EST 2010`

`989878 BC108 Mon Jan 08 00:00:00 EST 1990`

`878788 BC109 Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 EST 2000`

*******I WANT TO SEE OUTPUT LIKE THIS*******

`099909 BC107 Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 EST 2010`

`989878 BC108 Mon Jan 08 00:00:00 EST 1990`

`878788 BC109 Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 EST 2000`

`099909 BC101 Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2010`

`989878 BC102 Tue Jan 02 00:00:00 EST 1990`

`878788 BC103 Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 EST 2000`

`099909 BC104 Mon Jan 04 00:00:00 EST 2010`

`989878 BC105 Fri Jan 05 00:00:00 EST 1990`

`878788 BC106 Thu Jan 06 00:00:00 EST 2000`

Thanks

Comment: we need more infos to help you, like how your `ArrayList` stores dates and "other information".
See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/how-do-i-use-comparator-to-define-a-custom-sort-order

Comment: Oh *please* don't use `SimpleDateFormat`, it's obsolete and replaced by `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Similar (only next 3 days instead): [Sorting collection date field between two given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700048/sorting-collection-date-field-between-two-given-dates)

Comment: We need more clarity, please. Do you want to ignore year when deciding which are the last three days? If December 31 had been in your list, would it have counted as earlier or later than the others when deciding which are the last three days?

Comment: Also when the last date is January 9, do you want to see all persons with order date January 7, 8 and 9 first no matter if they are 1 person or 10 persons?

Comment: For your coming Stack Overflow questions you should also learn to show an effort on your own part for better reception. Questions showing no effort are very often downvoted and closed quickly. Even doing a simple search and noting in the question that you know that you need to use the sort method of your list and the `Comparator` interface but you don’t know how is better than nothing and will make more people prepared to make an effort to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified example, using Java streams, and replacing your murky Person-Order-LineItem combo class with a simple `Employee` class.

I define our `Employee` class as a Java 16+ [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) for brevity, but not important.

```java
record Employee( int id , String name , LocalDate hired ) { }
```

Notice that we use `java.time.LocalDate`, as you seem to want a date without a time-of-day. Tip: Never use `java.util.Date`, nor `Calendar` or `SimpleDateFormat`. These legacy classes are terribly flawed in design, and were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Create some sample data.

```java
List < Employee > employeeList =
        List.of(
                new Employee( 1 , "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.AUGUST , 10 ) ) ,
                new Employee( 1 , "Bob" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.AUGUST , 9 ) ) ,
                new Employee( 2 , "Carol" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.AUGUST , 8 ) ) ,
                new Employee( 3 , "Davis" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) ,
                new Employee( 4 , "Ernestine" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 24 ) ) ,
                new Employee( 5 , "Frank" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ) )
        );
```

Determine today's date. Time zone is important; for any given moment the date varies around the globe by time zone.

For this demo, we replace that dynamically-determined date with a hard-coded date.

```java
// LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.AUGUST , 10 );
LocalDate threeDaysAgo = today.minusDays( 3 );
```

Filter for the `Employee` objects whose hire-date is within the last three days. Collect into a `NavigableSet` where their order is maintained according to the `Comparator` we pass to constructor.

For convenience, we use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)). We pass a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `Employee :: hired`, the default getter method implicitly created by the compiler for a `record`.

```java
NavigableSet < Employee > recent = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparing( Employee :: hired ) );
recent.addAll( employeeList.stream().filter( employee -> ! employee.hired.isBefore( threeDaysAgo ) ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() ) );
```

Determine our longer-term employees by filtering the list for those objects not found in our `recent` set.

```java
NavigableSet < Employee > older = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparing( Employee :: hired ) );
older.addAll( employeeList.stream().filter( employee -> ! recent.contains( employee ) ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() ) );
```

You want a single list. So add the `recent` set to a new list, to be followed by adding the `older` set.

The iteration order in which the elements are added to our list is controlled by the fact that we used `NavigableSet` implementations that maintained a certain order.

```java
List < Employee > results = new ArrayList <>( employeeList.size() );
results.addAll( recent );
results.addAll( older );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "employeeList = " + employeeList );
System.out.println( "recent = " + recent );
System.out.println( "older = " + older );
System.out.println( "results = " + results );
```

When run.

> employeeList = [Employee[id=1, name=Alice, hired=2021-08-10], Employee[id=1, name=Bob, hired=2021-08-09], Employee[id=2, name=Carol, hired=2021-08-08], Employee[id=3, name=Davis, hired=2021-01-23], Employee[id=4, name=Ernestine, hired=2021-01-24], Employee[id=5, name=Frank, hired=2021-01-25]]
>
> recent = [Employee[id=2, name=Carol, hired=2021-08-08], Employee[id=1, name=Bob, hired=2021-08-09], Employee[id=1, name=Alice, hired=2021-08-10]]
>
> older = [Employee[id=3, name=Davis, hired=2021-01-23], Employee[id=4, name=Ernestine, hired=2021-01-24], Employee[id=5, name=Frank, hired=2021-01-25]]
>
> results = [Employee[id=2, name=Carol, hired=2021-08-08], Employee[id=1, name=Bob, hired=2021-08-09], Employee[id=1, name=Alice, hired=2021-08-10], Employee[id=3, name=Davis, hired=2021-01-23], Employee[id=4, name=Ernestine, hired=2021-01-24], Employee[id=5, name=Frank, hired=2021-01-25]]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me that's working now.

```
double pastFiveDays = DoubleTime.getDoubleDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(5));

    ArrayList<Header> salesList = list.getSalesHeaders();
        NavigableSet < Header> recent = new TreeSet<>( Comparator.comparing( Header:: getSalesDate ) );
        recent.addAll( salesList.stream().filter( salesorder -> (salesorder.getSalesDate() > pastFiveDays && salesorder.getUnit() !=1))
                .collect( Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new) ) );

        NavigableSet < Header> older = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparing( Header:: getSalesDate ) );
        older.addAll( salesList.stream().filter( salesorder -> ! recent.contains( salesorder ) && salesorder.getUnit() !=1 )
                .collect( Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new) ) );
```